# using JMeter if controller with csv input

Tags: csv, jmeter, load-testing

I'm load testing an API where I am taking my test data from a CSV

Here is how my csv looks like

[image]

and my if controller is like this

[image]

However, when I run the thread group, I get the following error:

```
2017/08/04 09:52:14 ERROR - jmeter.control.IfController: Check Country: error while processing [USA==USA]  
org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "USA" is not defined. (<cmd>#1)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3951)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3929) 
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:4019)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1851)   
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__4._c_script_0(<cmd>:1)  
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__4.call(<cmd>)   
at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393)     
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3282)  
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__4.call(<cmd>)   
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._cmd__4.exec(<cmd>)   
at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.evaluateString(Context.java:1219)     
at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController$RhinoJsEngine.evaluate(IfController.java:105)     
at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.evaluateCondition(IfController.java:187) 
at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.next(IfController.java:240)   
at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:222)    
at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:176) 
at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:222)    
at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:176)
at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123)   
at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:222)    
at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:176) 
at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123)   
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:87) 
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:247)    
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm new to jmeter, so I'm guessing I'm missing something here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after doing some research, I found that String expressions need to be double-quoted for them to work.

So, the following condition works

```
"${CTRY}"=="USA"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use [Groovy language for any form of scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) in JMeter so I would recommend setting your If Controller condition via [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) (available since [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30)), the relevant Groovy expression would be something like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('CTRY') == 'USA',)}
```